# Can we use hibernate stuff in AWS Lambda Program to connect with relevant database?

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written an AWS Lambda function (implemented handleRequest as usual, without db connect stuff it works fine) of , that actually suppose to connect with an Amazon hosted Oracle database.

For the same I have added Hibernate Util and relevant config file to connect to database. so that on the invocation of AWS Lambda function a specific record got inserted into the database.

But I am receiving below error, Is there anything I am missing here ?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.exercise.CurrentTime.handleRequest(CurrentTime.java:34)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)"
  ]
}
```

EDIT

I figured out that hibernate.cfg.xml wasn't added , and later I added all the requisite files, but at the end it gave following problems [everything worked well in my desktop] :

**My question do we have any example where hibernate based package uploaded as lambda function or AWS lambda service meant for minimal logic function.**

```
START RequestId: dcece63c-f0e8-11e5-9f50-edb8ba93d932 Version: $LATEST 
First Log :Type:Notification, requestId:dcece63c-f0e8-11e5-9f50-edb8ba93d932, function:simple-lambda-java-exercise, groupName:/aws/lambda/simple-lambda-java-exercise, logStreamName:2016/03/23/[$LATEST]6413c2ef43b14e1aad006f31ca92f260
Second Log :InputMessage :sample message
Maven + Hibernate + Oracle 
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.exercise.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17) at com.exercise.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8) at com.exercise.CurrentTime.handleRequest(CurrentTime.java:34) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2176) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2157) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137) at com.exercise.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13) ... 6 more  
END RequestId: dcece63c-f0e8-11e5-9f50-edb8ba93d932 
REPORT RequestId: dcece63c-f0e8-11e5-9f50-edb8ba93d932  Duration: 1368.02 ms    Billed Duration: 1400 ms Memory Size: 512 MB    Max Memory Used: 43 MB   
START RequestId: e798ae13-f0e8-11e5-a603-69c02723850a Version: $LATEST 
First Log :Type:Notification, requestId:e798ae13-f0e8-11e5-a603-69c02723850a, function:simple-lambda-java-exercise, groupName:/aws/lambda/simple-lambda-java-exercise, logStreamName:2016/03/23/[$LATEST]6413c2ef43b14e1aad006f31ca92f260
Second Log :InputMessage :sample message
Maven + Hibernate + Oracle 
Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil at com.exercise.CurrentTime.handleRequest(CurrentTime.java:34) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
END RequestId: e798ae13-f0e8-11e5-a603-69c02723850a 
REPORT RequestId: e798ae13-f0e8-11e5-a603-69c02723850a  Duration: 1.26 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB   
START RequestId: e9116b9c-f0e8-11e5-bccb-4f6d3966e31d Version: $LATEST 
First Log :Type:Notification, requestId:e9116b9c-f0e8-11e5-bccb-4f6d3966e31d, function:simple-lambda-java-exercise, groupName:/aws/lambda/simple-lambda-java-exercise, logStreamName:2016/03/23/[$LATEST]6413c2ef43b14e1aad006f31ca92f260
Second Log :InputMessage :sample message
Maven + Hibernate + Oracle 
Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil at com.exercise.CurrentTime.handleRequest(CurrentTime.java:34) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
END RequestId: e9116b9c-f0e8-11e5-bccb-4f6d3966e31d 
REPORT RequestId: e9116b9c-f0e8-11e5-bccb-4f6d3966e31d  Duration: 1.25 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB   
START RequestId: 2d150ad7-f0ec-11e5-afb5-e3e30ad68aea Version: $LATEST 
First Log :Type:Notification, requestId:2d150ad7-f0ec-11e5-afb5-e3e30ad68aea, function:simple-lambda-java-exercise, groupName:/aws/lambda/simple-lambda-java-exercise, logStreamName:2016/03/23/[$LATEST]6413c2ef43b14e1aad006f31ca92f260
Second Log :InputMessage :sample message
Maven + Hibernate + Oracle 
Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.exercise.HibernateUtil at com.exercise.CurrentTime.handleRequest(CurrentTime.java:34) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
END RequestId: 2d150ad7-f0ec-11e5-afb5-e3e30ad68aea 
REPORT RequestId: 2d150ad7-f0ec-11e5-afb5-e3e30ad68aea  Duration: 1.24 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB
```

Comment: It's saying a class wasn't included in the Lambda function you deployed. You didn't properly package that class into the deployment.

Comment: My bad, I did everything to dun the AWS lambda function, as I am new to this area so missed some security groups configuration and some other amazon specific stuff, with that problem got solved.

Comment: did you solve it? Show your example of pom.xml

Comment: @Dynamic , I removed the Hibernate stuff, and used plain JDBC way to connect lambda function with DB. Followed following URLs :http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your jar does not have libraries included in it, which needs at runtime. You will need your jar with all the dependencies. Consider using maven shade plugin or maven assembly plugin and verify that your jar contains all the required dependencies and then upload this jar. It should work.

Later you can consider using AWS layer for dependencies so that you don't have to bundle your jar with the dependencies.